# Getting counts of total substring matches from a full-text field in one table to another full-text field in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table loaded with text strings that i need to do a substring match on another text string field in another table and then spit out the counts

```
CREATE TABLE `subdiv_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `names` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE 'property' (
  ...
  'subdiv_name' varchar(70) 
)
```

i tried

```
SELECT count(*) AS count,
SUBSTRING(subdiv_names.subdiv, wp_realty_listingsdb.Subdivision) AS mtch
FROM wp_realty_listingsdb,subdiv_names
GROUP BY mtch
ORDER BY count DESC
```

but no of course.

some data subdiv_names.name

```
700 Ocean Drive
Barclay Condo Apts
Bay Colony
Coral Bay
...
```

and property.subdiv_name

```
Palm Beach Barclay Condo Apts Est 2
Old Jupiter Beach Road 700 Ocean Drive 
Old Jupiter Beach Road 700 Ocean Drive 
Palm Beach Barclay Condo Apts Est 2
Golfview Hgts 8 In Pb 24 Pgs 103 And 104
Bay Colony Heights
Paradise Cove At Palm Beach Lakes Condo
Palm Beach Barclay Condo Apts Est 2
WESTWOOD GARDENS
...
```

results desired

```
2 Old Jupiter Beach Road 700 Ocean Drive 
3 Palm Beach Barclay Condo Apts Est 2
1 Bay Colony Heights
0 Coral Bay
...
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a function that does this. `SUBSTRING()` doesn't do matching, it just returns the part of the string starting at a given position.

Comment: The `LOCATE()` function does an exact match for a substring, is that what you're looking for? It doesn't return a count of matches, just the position of the first match.

Comment: Can you edit the question with sample data and desired results?

Comment: @Barmar yes that is what the group by was trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `like` (or various other functions):

```
select p.subdivis, count(*)
from props p inner join
     subdiv_names n
     on concat(',', p.subdivis, ',') like concat('%,', n.subdiv, ',%')
group by p.subdivis;
```

I can't quite tell which set of data corresponds to which table.  You might need to swap the table names.

Comment: i tried this and am getting syntax errors so i cleaned up the OP

Comment: @menriquez . . . For some reason, I left out the `join` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correct then i wouldn't be needing `substring`. I think `LIKE`  will do the trick.

IF you can put snapshot of your expectation we can try for you or elaborate the question further.

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't do word searching.

Comment: It also doesn't return a count of matches, it just returns true or false.

Comment: Yah i though he need just to confirm the existance or am i mistaken?

Comment: i tried `GROUP BY Subdivis REGEXP...' but didn't work